# Version changes conflict with examples in documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Twice I tried to add rails 5.0 release to versions in https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby-on-rails/225/introduction-to-ruby-on-rails#t=201607211215320131392 , and both times edit was rejected as conflicting with some example additions/edits.

Do these need to be dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough, there was a bug in the diff merging code that compared a proposed change against possible conflicts. We erroneously rejected Version section changes in introduction topics even when there was no actual conflict.

This will be fixed with the next production build. Thanks!